# create sub-directories using Python on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

How to automatically create 5 sub-directories using Python on Ubuntu?

i tried to create a .txt file with the folders name in it, than tried to execute the following command but its not working.

```
python -c 'import sys,os,codecs;[os.mkdir(d) for d in codecs.open(sys.argv[1],"r",&q­uot;utf8")]' subdirectory.txt
```

i believe this command will create folders in 1 folder instead of creating sub directories within a folder so i am wrong there

I am currently trying to perform this action on my Virtual box on my Ubuntu 12.04.

i would like to see my output to be

```
/home/user01/testdirectory/subdirectory
/home/user01/testdirectory/subdirectory/sub1
/home/user01/testdirectory/subdirectory/sub1/sub2
/home/user01/testdirectory/subdirectory/sub1/sub2/sub3
```

and so on

Comment: Try to use ```os.makedirs() ``` instead of ```os.mkdir```

Comment: @Alex I tried exactly the same thing using IDLE (Python 3.5 32-bit) on my windows machine and it works successfully.
But on Ubuntu its throwing some errors

Comment: @omar89: What's the error?

Comment: on IDLE i used 
>>> import os
>>> os.makedirs('dir1/dir2/dir3')
>>> os.getcwd()
The above works only on IDLE and creates sub directories on my computer, but on Ubuntu even this keeps throwing errors

Comment: @KevinGuan SyntaxError: invalid syntax
i see "^" below the & sign before "quot" in the code

Comment: @omar89: The full Traceback would be helpful, please [edit] your question and add the error message.

Comment: @KevinGuan on my Ubuntu it doesnt allow me to copy and paste. I tried installing the GUI but it doesnt allow to install anything always throws some error. WHen ever i try to install anything it throws some package is missing/broken  error  message that is only available from another source
FOr example if i try to install sudo apt-get install tree

 it trows E: Package 'tree' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

The `&quot;` is obviously not valid Python. I guess you copied this from a web site with broken HTML coding. The correct syntax is

```
codecs.open(sys.argv[1],"r","utf8")
```

Comment: I'd suggest also add *use `os.makedirs()` instead of `os.mkdir()`* as Alex's comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand you correctly. Do you want to create just a long path of directories in one shoy? If so, it can be achieved by os.makedirs('/long/path/is/here').

If you want to create a bunch of directories before creating file you could use os.path.dirname to get a directory, create a path, and then create a file.

If you need to create a bunch of directories taken from file then:

```
cat textfile.txt | xargs -n 1 python -c 'import os, sys;os.makedirs(sys.argv[1])'
```

even better. You don't need python.

```
cat file.txt | xargs -n 1 mkdir -p
```

Comment: The `cat` is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix.award.html). `xargs` has an `-a` option to read from a file if redirection is somehow inconvenient.

Comment: @Volodymyr i fixed the directory issue. Now after executing the first command provided by you, It is creating sub directories under my main directory. 
TO fix my .txt file i change folders names on each lines to dir1/dir2/dir3 

Thanks alot for all the help.